# Can't get jQuery to work with Icefaces + Liferay

Tags: jquery, jsf, xhtml, liferay, icefaces

I'm trying to develop a simple Liferay portlet with the Icefaces framework and cannot get jQuery to work.

The main problem is, that I can't load the jQuery library properly. Whenever I add script tags to my xhtml header like this

```
<h:head>
    <script></script>
</h:head>
```

the page shows an error message:

> failed to append text[ ] into #document

So I tried loading the jQuery libray with the *h:outputScript* tag instead, but in Icefaces, the target="head" option doesn't work - see http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-8313.

```
<h:outputScript library="scripts" name="jquery-1.9.1.js" target="head" />
```

So, at this point I'm clueless who to include the jQuery (or any javascript) library.

Please don't suggest using another framework. Icefaces is demanded in future projects, so I have to get used to it.

All I'm trying to do is something like this: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Thanks in advance,
Fabi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you know that this `<h:head>` tag would ultimately generate an HTML `<head>` tag.

And since portlets are just fragments they should not contain any type of `<head>` tag, so in liferay you can specify your javascript either in [`<header-portlet-javascript>`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.1-ga2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd#L656) or [`<header-portal-javascript>`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.1-ga2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd#L650) element in [`liferay-portlet.xml`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.1-ga2/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L18).

Or else include your javscript library in the theme you would create inside the [`portal_normal.vm`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.1-ga2/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/portal_normal.vm#L10).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Loading the library with <header-portlet-javascript> works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a JS-Library with the `<header-portlet-javascript>` in the `liferay-portlet.xml` file. Maybe this (older) [example](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/5241428) can help you.